Issues getting the Netplan 01-netcfg.yaml file to work for my interface
Tried spinning up a new OpenVPN server (Ubunto ver 22.04) via Hyper-v VM and started out by
running sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml file and set it up per OpenVPN recommended settings and did not work stating"
/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:1:1: Error in network definition: expected mapping (check indentation)

Ive tried about 10 different combinations  but none of them are working - Then had OpenVPN support in with me and they told me to run netplan get command and then said I need to reach out to Ubuntu Support.   Here is what I currently have set for this file along with another 2 examples of what I have tried.....
network: 
  version: 2 
  renderer: networkd 
  ethernets: 
    eth0: 
      dhcp4: no 
      addresses: 
       - 172.16.69.230/24 
      gateway4: 172.16.69.254 
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [172.16.69.20]

network: 
  version: 2 
  renderer: networkd 
  ethernets: 
    eth0: 
      dhcp4: false 
      dhcp6: false 
      addresses: 
      - 172.16.69.230/24 
      routes: 
      - to: default 
        via: 172.16.69.254 
      nameservers: 
       addresses: [172.16.69.20]

network: 
  version: 2 
  ethernets: 
    eth0: 
      dhcp4: false 
      dhcp6: false 
      addresses: 
        - 172.16.69.230/24 
      routes: 
        - to: default 
          via: 172.16.69.254 
      nameservers: 
        addresses: 
          - 172.16.69.20


The configs you've posted look correctly formatted (aside from the fact they show as a single config file with 3 separate network stanzas, which is invalid; I've submitted an edit of the question to try to clear this up).  But the error message suggests you may have an indentation error, which may be true in the source config files but not evident in what you've pasted here.  Please ensure that the network: key starts in the first column of the file.
Here is a reduced configuration which should match the behavior you're trying to get with the above configs.  Note that gateway4 is deprecated, and false is the default for both dhcp4 and dhcp6.  And in your second example, the mapping for routes is not correctly indented.
network: 
  version: 2 
  renderer: networkd 
  ethernets: 
    eth0: 
      addresses: [ "172.16.69.230/24" ]
      routes: 
        - to: default 
          via: 172.16.69.254 
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [ 172.16.69.20 ]

